# XSLT 2.0 reporting element only once

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm stuck with following XSLT 2.0 processing problem:
How to get element (named as 'type' in the next sample input) reported with full information only once and then later just with reference (href)?

### Sample input XML

```
<top-level>
<group id="1">
    <object id="objectA">
        <property>
            <value>Jack</value>
        </property>
        <type-tref>/types/type1</type-tref>
    </object>
    <object id="objectB">
        <property>
            <value>Jim</value>
        </property>
        <type-tref>/types/type2</type-tref>
    </object>
    <object id="objectC">
        <property>
            <value>John</value>
        </property>
        <type-tref>/types/type1</type-tref>
    </object>
</group>
<group id="2">
    <object id="objectD">
        <property>
            <value>Jill</value>
        </property>
        <type-tref>/types/type1</type-tref>
    </object>
</group>
<specialObjects>
    <object id="objectE">
        <property>
            <value>Mark</value>
        </property>
        <type-tref>/types/type1</type-tref>
    </object>
    <object id="objectF">
        <property>
            <value>David</value>
        </property>
        <type-tref>/types/type3</type-tref>
    </object>
</specialObjects>
<types>
    <type id="type1">
        <name>myFirst</name>
        <color>blue</color>
        <format>circle</format>
    </type>
    <type id="type2">
        <name>mySecond</name>
        <color>red</color>
        <format>rectangle</format>
    </type>
    <type id="type3">
        <name>myThird</name>
        <color>black</color>
        <format>empty</format>
    </type>
</types>
</top-level>
```

Now my XSLT script should process the input XML-file so that referred types ('type1', 'type2' and 'type3') will be resulted only once (with full details) in the output (in the sample only for 'objectA', 'objectB' and 'objectF' (while they have the 1st references) and for other cases just use the href.

### Expected output:

```
<file>
<person id="objectA">
    <name>Jack</name>
    <myType id="1">
        <myName>myFirst</myName>
        <myColor>blue</myColor>
        <myFormat>circle</myFormat>
    </myType>
</person>
<person id="objectB">
    <name>Jim</name>
    <myType id="2">
        <myName>mySecond</myName>
        <myColor>red</myColor>
        <myFormat>rectangle</myFormat>
    </myType>
</person>
<person id="objectC">
    <name>John</name>
    <myType href="#1"></myType>
</person>
<person id="objectD">
    <name>Jill</name>
    <myType href="#1"></myType>
</person>
<person id="objectE">
    <name>Mark</name>
    <myType href="#1"></myType>
</person>
<person id="objectF">
    <name>David</name>
    <myType id="2">
        <myName>myThird</myName>
        <myColor>black</myColor>
        <myFormat>empty</myFormat>
    </myType>
</person>
</file>
```

How to know if element has already been processed (and now only the reference is needed)?

Or should I collect all the objects (from 'group(s)' as well as from the 'specialObjects'-elements) somehow together? (Just to avoid situation that 'myType' information would be generated n-times for each person-element while going through the objects in the source)

Any help/tip really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use keys and identify the first `object`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:key name="by-type" match="object" use="type-tref"/>

<xsl:key name="ref-type" match="type" use="@id"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="types" select="//types/type"/>

<xsl:template match="top-level">
  <file>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//object"/>
  </file>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object[generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-type', type-tref)[1])]">
  <person id="{@id}">
    <name><xsl:value-of select="property/value"/></name>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref-type', tokenize(type-tref, '/')[last()])"/>
  </person>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-type', type-tref)[1]))]">
  <person id="{@id}">
    <name><xsl:value-of select="property/value"/></name>
    <myType href="#{index-of($types, key('ref-type', tokenize(type-tref, '/')[last()]))}"/>
  </person>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="type">
  <myType>
    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:number/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </myType>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="type//*">
  <xsl:element name="my{upper-case(substring(local-name(), 1, 1))}{substring(local-name(), 2)}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is

```
<file>
   <person id="objectA">
      <name>Jack</name>
      <myType id="1">
        <myName>myFirst</myName>
        <myColor>blue</myColor>
        <myFormat>circle</myFormat>
      </myType>
   </person>
   <person id="objectB">
      <name>Jim</name>
      <myType id="2">
        <myName>mySecond</myName>
        <myColor>red</myColor>
        <myFormat>rectangle</myFormat>
      </myType>
   </person>
   <person id="objectC">
      <name>John</name>
      <myType href="#1"/>
   </person>
   <person id="objectD">
      <name>Jill</name>
      <myType href="#1"/>
   </person>
   <person id="objectE">
      <name>Mark</name>
      <myType href="#1"/>
   </person>
   <person id="objectF">
      <name>David</name>
      <myType id="3">
        <myName>myThird</myName>
        <myColor>black</myColor>
        <myFormat>empty</myFormat>
      </myType>
   </person>
</file>
```

[edit] Ian had the same idea but used a more elegant, XSLT 2.0 way of expressing it so I will post an edit of my stylesheet with his use of the `is` operator to check the identity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:key name="by-type" match="object" use="type-tref"/>

<xsl:key name="ref-type" match="type" use="@id"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="types" select="//types/type"/>

<xsl:template match="top-level">
  <file>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//object"/>
  </file>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object[. is key('by-type', type-tref)[1]]">
  <person id="{@id}">
    <name><xsl:value-of select="property/value"/></name>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref-type', tokenize(type-tref, '/')[last()])"/>
  </person>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object[not(. is key('by-type', type-tref)[1])]">
  <person id="{@id}">
    <name><xsl:value-of select="property/value"/></name>
    <myType href="#{index-of($types, key('ref-type', tokenize(type-tref, '/')[last()]))}"/>
  </person>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="type">
  <myType>
    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:number/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </myType>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="type//*">
  <xsl:element name="my{upper-case(substring(local-name(), 1, 1))}{substring(local-name(), 2)}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good case for defining a *key* on the `type-tref` elements, then when you hit one you can check whether it is the first mention of that key value and take the appropriate action.  You could use another key to pull out the `type` for each `type-tref`

```xml
<xsl:key name="trefKey" match="type-tref" use="." />
<xsl:key name="typeById" match="type" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="type-tref[. is key('trefKey', .)[1]]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('typeById', tokenize(., '/')[last()])" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="type-tref">
  <myType href="#{generate-id(key('typeById', tokenize(., '/')[last()]))}" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="type">
  <myType id="{generate-id()}">
    <!-- insert child elements here -->
  </myType>
</xsl:template>
```

Here I'm just using the result of `generate-id` for the ID attributes, so they won't necessarily be sequential numbers but they will be internally consistent (and this isn't necessarily a bad thing - "IDs" in the XML sense are supposed to be valid *names*, which in particular means they shouldn't start with a digit).